# error unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

While calling using alamofire https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=(self.startlat,self.startlng)&destination=(self.endlat,self.endlng)

I am getting this error all time:

> 'fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value'

I also try this

```
if let slat = startlat {
    if let slng = self.startlng {
        if let elat = self.endlat {
            if let elng = self.endlng {
                Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=\(slat,slng)&destination=\(elat,elng)" , encoding: .JSON)
                .responseJSON { response in
                    let res = response.result.value!
                    self.estimatedDistance = (res["routes"]!![0]["legs"]!![0]["distance"]!!["value"] as! Int)/1000
                    self.estimatedTime = (res["routes"]!![0]["legs"]!![0]["duration"]!!["value"] as! Int)/60
                    print("\(self.estimatedDistance) - \(self.estimatedTime)")

               }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: `guard/else` is your friend ;)

Comment: You still have several forced unwrappings. Which line does the debugger cursor point to?

Comment: keep force unwrapping is never a good idea, if u feel too lazy for `if let` or `guard let` then consider use [Swifty JSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON), it will help

Answer (score 0):

JSON result from Google apis call:

```
{
   "geocoded_waypoints" : [
      {
         "geocoder_status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
      },
      {
         "geocoder_status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
      }
   ],
   "routes" : [],
   "status" : "NOT_FOUND"
}
```

It seems you are trying to access `res["routes"][0]!!`, but in this case (in your link) `res["routes"]` JSON element is an empty array.

Comment: But this direct value link "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=28.6691565,2077.4537578&destination=28.4594965,2077.0266383" is working

Comment: Yes link is fully working, but in routes element you are trying to get first value of the array and but the array is empty. You have to check if array has values before getting one of them.

Comment: "'\(self.startlat)'" automatically add "(" in string how to avoid that??